# Xamarin.Forms: share a link on Facebook with SharePlugin on iOS

Tags: facebook, plugins, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, share

I've implemented the **[SharePlugin](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin)** in my **Xamarin.Forms project**.

This works fine, but I meet a **little "problem" on iOS**: when I share a link, I haven't the choice to post it on **Facebook**:

[image: My app - no Facebook]

This option doesn't seem to be avalaible in the **Activities list**:

[image: My app - activities without Facebook]

On **Android**, the Facebook option is well available:

[image: My app - Android]

However, if I use the [**SharePlugin sample**](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin/tree/master/Common/SharePlugin/samples), the "Facebook" option is well available on iOS and in the activities:

[image: sample - with Facebook]

[image: sample - activities]

I share the link like this:

```
private void OnShareIconClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!CrossShare.IsSupported)
        return;
    CrossShare.Current.Share(new Plugin.Share.Abstractions.ShareMessage
    {
        Title = "MyApp",
        Text = _vm.AgendaEvent.encart_titre,
        Url = _vm.AgendaEvent.infos_url
    });
}
```

***Would you have any explanation?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to `FinishedLaunching` in AppDelegate.cs:

```
Plugin.Share.ShareImplementation.ExcludedUIActivityTypes.Clear();
```

It will clear the ExcludedUIActivityTypes list. Then Facebook extension will show.